# jQuery find ID of clicked button by class

Tags: jquery, button

I have numerous buttons on my page with the same class names. However these buttons have different ID's. How do i do this:

```
$(".vote").click(function(){
     var id = $(this).{ID OF CLICKED BUTTON};
});
```

How can i make this pseudo code work?

Thanks

Comment: WOW, almost 6 identical answers :)

Comment: yes, but only one of them is right.

Comment: "Right" or "Best"?  I wouldn't go so far as to use terms like "wrong" or "right" when it comes to a set of solutions, especially when those who are answering are all at varying skill levels within their careers.  :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
$(".vote").click(function(){
     var id = this.id;
});
```

The ID is accessible directly from the element. There's absolutely no need to use a jQuery method.

Comment: I think you meant "no need" :-) (SO won't allow me to make such a small edit.)

Answer (score 18):

With jQuery object (not necessary)

```
$(".vote").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Without jQuery object (faster)

```
$(".vote").click(function(){
  var id = this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked just fine for me,

```
$(".vote").click( (clicked) => {
     var id = clicked.target.id;
});
```

Comment: That one trick which never misses.

Answer (score 1):

i think this also work

```
 $("body").on("click",".vote",function(){
    var id = this.id;
 });
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically added buttons you can try the following method. above given method will only work if the button is present while loading the page

```
$(document).on('click','.vote',function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$(document).on('click','.vote',(event)=>{
     var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
})
```

M sure you never face any problem with this solution in any situation.

Answer (score -1):

use this :

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Yup, I saw that.  By all means use jQuery for the event handler, but please _don't_ use it just to get `this.id` out inside the handler.

Comment: This won't work for complex codes.

Answer (score -2):

You could use

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: -1 for `$(this).attr('id')` instead of just `this.id`

Answer (score -2):

Using attr:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

.attr allows you to get html tag attributes by name.