# Multiple buttons with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

SOLVED: Not enough coffee - the event listener was being added before the buttons were created.

Im creating a table from HTML LocalStorage like so:

```
for (i = 1; i <= localStorage['count']; i++) {
        tableHtml = tableHtml + "<tr><td><button class='delete' id=" + i + ">Delete</button></td><td>" + localStorage['fullName' + i] + "</td><td>" + localStorage['email' + i] + "</td><td>" + localStorage['phoneNum' + i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
```

This works great, however the delete button is proving troublesome.

I saw this:

[jQuery find ID of clicked button by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938876/jquery-find-id-of-clicked-button-by-class)

So I assumed i could do this:

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    alert('delete clicked for id: ' + $(this).id);
});
```

However, it doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: Watch carefully the code in the question you have posted and you will find the error

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is incorrect. Don't ever do it. If you have multiple elements with the same ID that ID should be a `class` instead

Comment: @ZachSaucier The code that OP has doesn't produce elements with the same ID

Comment: You obviously didn't read the answer of the question you linked so why would you read them here ?

Comment: I think you'll find I did.

Comment: @laaposto so what exactly do you think the problem is?  The HTML isn't perfectly formed (missing or incorrect quote marks around the ID attribute's value) but nor is it so badly formed that it wouldn't parse, unless the OP is on a pre-HTML5 browser that won't accept the numeric IDs.

Comment: where are you binding the click event in relation to when the elements are being added to the page? You are better off either using `on` or `live` for your binding so you can ensure current and future elements are bound. If not you will need to add the click binding after the els are added to the page.

Comment: @user3896192 please close and/or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you binding the click event? If it's before the element exists, you'll want to use .on.

```
$('body').on('click','.delete', function(){
    alert('delete clicked for id: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Check out a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/B486r/).

Comment: I'd +1 you for reading the comments and noticing that the OP already fixed his problem by registering the event handler at the right time, but then I'd have to -1 you for using `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id` ... ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't that be 2x -1's? -1 as I didn't read the comments (and being 8 minutes too late..!), and -1 for using .attr('id')?  (For anyone wondering:  [.id  is much quicker](http://jsperf.com/this-id-vs-this-attr-id).)

Comment: just call it evens already and don't push your luck! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

you can get the **id** of element by using **javascript** without using **jquery** wrapper like this:

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    alert('delete clicked for id: ' + this.id); // get id via javascript
});
```

or:

```
 $(".delete").click(function () {
        alert('delete clicked for id: ' + $(this)[0].id); // via javascript object
    });
```

If you see the [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938876/jquery-find-id-of-clicked-button-by-class) reffered in question it is also getting id using javascript (`this.id`)

if you want to get via jquery then:

```
 $(".delete").click(function () {
            alert('delete clicked for id: ' + $(this).attr("id")); // via jquery object
        });
```

Comment: or `$(this).attr('id')`, but that's the naive jQuery beginner newbie way, and `this.id` should always be used instead.

Comment: Cheers - not working though?

Comment: missing a second double quote `$(this).attr("id"));`

Answer (score 0):

use pure javascript:

```
this.id
```

or jquery

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

as `$(this)` is jquery object. and you are trying to get javascript property id. You need to first convert the object to javascript.

```
$(this)[0].id;
```

Comment: Thanks... I have tried both, neither seem to work

Comment: "Pure jQuery" - given jQuery just makes using javascript easier I don't think that's the right way to say it

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements shouldn't have numbers as the first character of id.
Change your code to something like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= localStorage['count']; i++) {
    tableHtml = tableHtml + "<tr><td><button class='delete' id=del-id" + i + ">Delete</button> </td><td>" + localStorage['fullName' + i] + "</td><td>" + localStorage['email' + i] + "</td><td>" + localStorage['phoneNum' + i] + "</td></tr>";
}
```

And

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    alert('delete clicked for id: ' + $(this).prop('id');
});
```

This should take you on the right track.
REMEMBER that .prop() function is jQuery 1.10+ specific.
If you are using an older version use .attr()

As some people here mentioned - id's can be numeric as of HTML5
still using them in a numeric form might generate rather unpleasant problems.
Link in the comments below from one of the users.

Comment: Yes, they can, since HTML5.  However CSS3 doesn't permit it within selectors so it's still not a good idea.

Comment: ergo - they can't. If you can set something just so u can't use it - its pointless

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute - I was under the impression that IDs were allowd numeric value as of HTML5?

Comment: @wick3d no, I didn't say they can't be used, they're explicitly legal now.  However a CSS stylesheet cannot use e.g. `#1` to refer to such an element.  That doesn't make them useless, just _less useful_.

Comment: @Alnitak I edited my answer noting your informations. Thank you.