# How to change the value in the input field while we click on dynamically created edit icons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here in the code there is ajax which assigning the values to the fields but there is the edit icon which is created dynamically it means that how many address you added in the database then number of times edit icon will be created. My need is that when I click on first button then it will alert its id value and when I clicked on the other one then it will alert its id value
Following is my code I tried:-

```
var full_url = document.URL; // Get current url
var url_array = full_url.split('=') // Split the string into an array with / as separator
var UserId = url_array[url_array.length-1];  // Get the last part of the array (-1)
$.ajax({
    url:"url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data:{"UserId":UserId},
    success: function(response){
        if (response.response.total_record[0].status === "active") {
            $('#email').html(response.response.total_record[0].email);
            $('#name').html(response.response.total_record[0].first_name+" "+response.response.total_record[0].last_name);
            $('#first').val(response.response.total_record[0].first_name);
            $('#last').val(response.response.total_record[0].last_name);
            $('#phone').val(response.response.total_record[0].phone_number);
            $('#alternative').val(response.response.total_record[0].alternative_number);
            $('#id').val(response.response.total_record[0]._id);
            $('#status').val(response.response.total_record[0].status)
            if (response.response.total_record[0].status === "active") {
                $('#activate').hide();
            }
            if (response.response.total_record[0].status === "deactivate") {                    $('#activate').show();
                $("#deactivate").hide();
            }
            $.each(response.response.total_record[0].address,function(i,item){
                console.log(response.response.total_record[0].address[i])
                $('#edit_id').val(response.response.total_record[0].address[i]._id)
            $('.cards').append('<div class="location-list"><header class="header_title"><div class="location_heading"><h3>Location:</h3></div><div class="edit_icon"><a class="editByAnchor" id='+response.response.total_record[0].address[i]._id+' href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_address"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></div></header><div id="dAddress" class="location-detial"><p><span id='+response.response.total_record[0].address[i]._id+'>'+response.response.total_record[0].address[i].address+'</span></p></div></div>');
            });                 
        }
    }
});
```

Html

```
<input type="hidden" id = "edit_id" value= "">
```

Jquery for finding the clicked

```
$('.editByAnchor').change(function() {
            alert("You just clicked checkbox with the name " + this.id)
});
```

Produces the output

```
<a class="editByAnchor" id="1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_address"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
/*more like this but id will be change base on the dynamically fields*/
```

The above output `anchor tag` having `id` attribute it will assigned dynamically as you see my code so how will I get the `id` attribute of each icon by clicking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By taking the reference of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938876/jquery-find-id-of-clicked-button-by-class) I post a answer for this everything is alright I have to change my code by following

```
$(".editByAnchor").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically created element use `on()`. Also you have to use `click` event instead of `change`:

```
$('.editByAnchor').on('click', function() {
    alert("You just clicked checkbox with the name " + this.id)
});
```

Comment: yeah this works too thanks for your valueable answer @Mamun